# Filter array by values from another array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I have a array:

```
    [
        {
            "website": "www.aaa.aaa", 
            "score": 90,
            "tags": [ "Video Online"]
        },
        {
            "website": "www.bbb.bbb", 
            "score": 90,
            "tags": ["Streaming Video"]
        },
        {
            "website": "www.ccc.ccc", 
            "score": 90,
            "tags": ["Video"]
        }
    ]
```

I want filter tag with 'Video' for this array. After filter with keyword 'Video'. I want to result with all object 'tags' have contain 'Video' by javascript ES5 or ES6.

I have written below code but it only working with args == values of array:

```
transform(val, args) {
        //console.log(args[0]);
        if(typeof args[0] === 'undefined') {
            return val;
        }

        return val.filter((el) => {
            //console.log(el.tags);
            return el.tags.indexOf(args[0]) != -1;  // return array[2]
        });
    }
```

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: Why are the `"tags"` properties arrays at all, when they all seem to contain  a single string? Can you give a slightly more realistic example?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

Comment: @nnnnnn I'd imagine since `tags` is plural that there can be multiple tags, just like on this post

Comment: @CJxD - Yes of course, except it looks like multiple tags were included separated by spaces. If the arrays can have multiple elements it would be nice for the sample input to reflect this. (Sample *output* would be helpful, too.)

Answer (score 2):

Essentially you want to make a custom matching function. You seem to be programming functionally, that's cool - it lends itself well to this kind of problem. I've added a few suggestions to make it more robust.

I've never seen the `((elem) => { func })` shorthand before, so I'll assume that's actually a thing!

1. Make sure you are searching in the same case. If your search string is all caps, and the tags aren't, they wont match.
2. There is a `.some` method which returns true if one or more of the iterated elements matches some condition: that's the kind of thing we want to see if any keyword matches.
3. You'll want to further split all tags by the space character so 'video' will return all tags with the word 'video' in. Alternatively, you could just have each word as a separate tag (e.g. ["Streaming", "Video"])

This is what your transform function would look like taking these suggestions into account:

```js
    data = [{"website": "www.aaa.aaa","score": 90,"tags": ["Video Online"]},
            {"website": "www.bbb.bbb","score": 90,"tags": ["Streaming Video"]},
            {"website": "www.ccc.ccc","score": 90,"tags": ["Video"]}];

    function transform(val, args) {
      if (typeof args[0] === 'undefined') {
        return val;
      }

      // Convert all arguments to lower case
      args = args.map(function(arg) {
        return arg.toLowerCase();
      });

      // Return elements of val that match
      return val.filter(function(el) {

        // Return true if one or more of the tags match
        return el.tags.some(function(tag) {

          // Convert tags to lowercase and split by space
          tagwords = tag.toLowerCase().split(' ');

          // Return true if any argument matches one of the split tags
          return args.some(function(arg) {
            return tagwords.some(function(word) {
              return word == arg;
            });
          });
        });
      });
    };

    filtered = transform(data, ["online", "streaming"]);
    document.write(JSON.stringify(filtered));
```

Comment: I've made a JSFiddle for this. Your transform function can take any number of arguments in `args`, it's case-insensitive, and it matches part-phrases of tags. http://jsfiddle.net/k51ryqnq/1/

Comment: You can insert runable code snippets here using the button two to the right of the `{}` button in edit mode. Also, the "thing" you're referring to are ECMAScript 2015 [*arrow functions*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-arrow-function-definitions). Also available at [*MDN*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions). ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Now I get it. You want to pass an array of values and if any of the *tags* properties contain any of the values, return that object, so:

```js
var array = [{"website": "www.aaa.aaa","score": 90,"tags": [ "Video Online"]},
  {"website": "www.bbb.bbb","score": 90,"tags": ["Streaming Video"]},
  {"website": "www.ccc.ccc","score": 90,"tags": ["Video"]}];


function transform(val, args) {
    if(typeof args[0] === 'undefined') {
      return val;
    }

    // Get the members of val whose tags property has
    // any of the values in args
    return val.filter(function(el) {

       // Returns true for the first match, otherwise false
       return args.some(function(s){return el.tags.indexOf(s) != -1});
    });
}

document.write(JSON.stringify(transform(array, ['Video','Video Online'])));
```

Or if you want to use arrow funcitons:

```
function transform(val, args) {
    if(typeof args[0] !== 'undefined')
        return val.filter(el => args.some(s => el.tags.indexOf(s) != -1));
}
```